# Is there an application to convert the pdf files to a flipbook

Tags: pdf

I would like to know if there is an application or a add to libre office, so as to make the pdf files to flipbooks! Many thanks!

Comment: User [SevenSonicStructures](http://askubuntu.com/users/475849/sevensonicstructures) posted an answer suggesting [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), but then deleted it. Seemed worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Calibre can do that for you and more. http://calibre-ebook.com/

It has support for many formats, including PDF and EPUB, which is what you seem to be looking for. You can convert to any ebook format, fix/add table of contents, adjust font size and formatting, and many other things.  I use it constantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Calibre to convert .pdf files(or any e dpcument format) into another. You'll find plenty of options so if not directly, you can convert to an intermediate format first.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used it, but a friend of mine enjoys 'Sigil' an alternative to the standard Calibre - if you're looking for something outside of Calibre, that is.